# Is Craigslist '48 hours between posts' limit per category or per item per category?

Tags: craigslist

From the [Craigslist FAQ](http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/faq#postOften):

> You may post to one category and in one city, no more than once every
>   48 hours.
>
> If you try to post something similar to an active post of yours on the
>   site, you may get a blocked message

The first sentence makes it look simple: one post per category within 48 hours. However the second makes it seem like you're fine if you're not advertising the same thing. Is the limit once per category, or once per item per category?

Answer (score 2):

Craigslist's ["Common reasons for posting removal"](http://www.craigslist.org/about/help/reasons) seems to resolve the difficulty. It says:

> Post each item/offering no more than once every 48 hours please.

Maybe we should [write to Craigslist](https://sfbay.craigslist.org/contact) and ask them to replace the poor wording "You may post to one category and in one city, no more than once every 48 hours" with the better wording "Post each item/offering no more than once every 48 hours please."

Could someone please do this and let us know what happened? Please leave a comment below with the results.